# how to import csv-file via 'roo' gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

please help import csv-file.

i install gem 'roo' and gem 'iconv'. i make scaffold products nad form for import file:

```
<%= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
def import
  Product.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

models/product.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

i use this popular tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true

but after load csv-file via form, browser display follow:

```
NameError in ProductsController#import
uninitialized constant Csv
```

and console display follow error

```
message:#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000060f36a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151015-18667-14nvfde.csv>, @original_filename="products (2).csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"products (2).csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NameError (uninitialized constant Csv):
  app/models/product.rb:25:in `open_spreadsheet'
  app/models/product.rb:11:in `import'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:82:in `import'
```

i try in model replace:

```
when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
```

on

```
when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
```

but problem not solve.

in this topic i asked to Suraj about tweaking, but but received no response.

please help impoer csv-file

Comment: did you implement the

config/application.rb
require 'csv'
require 'iconv'


part ?

Comment: Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore) what i got this may be solve your error

Answer (score 0):

Only add require 'csv'

and

```
`when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)`
```

but i use with another method:

```
`when ".csv" then CSV.parse(File.read(file.path), :headers => true)`
```

and to read use this

```
`spreadsheet.each do |row|
   line = []
   row.to_a.each_with_index do |val|
     line.push(val[1].to_s)
   end
   rows.push(line)
end`
```

Answer (score -1):

Change Csv.new to CSV.new what is the error after doing that?

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new

Update

Instead of doing:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
```

try doing:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('./name_of_file')
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
```

Comment: browser display: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: browser display: Can't detect the type of ./name_of_file - please use the :extension option to declare its type.